# NLog ElasticSearch structuredlogging

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nlog

I need to send NLog log messages to Kibana. Now I'm using NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch with structuredlogging.json but in this case elastic treats message as string and not as json. In general I need Kibana to treat message as object by fields of which I can make future analytics.

So how to force nlog or NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch to send data to elasticsearch to be treated as json?

Here is what i have now:

```
  {
    "_index": "logstash-2017.10.12",
    "_type": "logevent",
    "_id": "AV8QvCAHXFqCIKUdDl_1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-12T13:18:05.0609218Z",
      "level": "Error",
      "message": """{"TimeStamp":"2017-10-12T13:18:05.060Z","Level":"Error","LoggerName":"testApp.Program","Message":"error","CallSite":"testApp.Program.Main","error":"error0"}"""
    }
  }
```

And it needs to be something like this:

```
  {
    "_index": "logstash-2017.10.12",
    "_type": "logevent",
    "_id": "AV8QvCAHXFqCIKUdDl_1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2017-10-12T13:18:05.0609218Z",
      "level": "Error",
      "message": {
        "TimeStamp":"2017-10-12T13:18:05.060Z",
        "Level":"Error",
        "LoggerName":"testApp.Program",
        "Message":"error",
        "CallSite":"testApp.Program.Main",
        "error":"error0"
      }
    }
  }
```

Current NLog.config looks so:

```
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000" >
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" layout="${structuredlogging.json}">
  </target>
</target>
```

Comment: Looks like the message is already encoded as Json, and then ${structuredlogging.json} performs one more encoding. Maybe you should just use the NLog-JsonLayout and configure the formatting yourself: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout (encode = false for the ${message})

Comment: No, first time message encoded in ${structuredlogging.json}. As I understand NLog-JsonLayout will just make a json, but the problem is dipper, in NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch. According to it's source code it sends message as string and there is no way to send it as a part of dictionary i.e. Json.

Comment: NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch and NLog.StructuredLogging.Json doesn't work together out of the box. You have to choose, and if you choose the later then you have to create a custom target that calls IElasticLowLevelClient with the Json received from NLog.StructuredLogging.Json. Maybe create an issue for NLog.StructuredLogging.Json about how to integrate with elastic search.

Comment: @show Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @yosbel , No I have not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="500" >
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch">
     <field name="msg" layout="${structuredlogging.json}" layoutType="System.Object" />
  </target>
</target>
```

Alternative you can do this (Without NLog.StructuredLogging.Json):

```
<target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="500" >
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" includeAllProperties="true">
     <field name="TimeStamp" layout="${date:format=o}" />
     <field name="Level" layout="${level}" />
     <field name="LoggerName" layout="${logger}" />
     <field name="Message" layout="${message}" />
     <field name="CallSite" layout="${callsite}" />
     <field name="error" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </target>
</target>
```

Alternative you can do this (Using [EcsLayout](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog/)):

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    <add assembly="Elastic.Apm.NLog"/>
    <add assembly="Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog"/>
</extensions>
<targets>
   <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" enableJsonLayout="true">
       <layout xsi:type="EcsLayout" />
   </target>
</targets>
```

Comment: Does this work with EcsLayout?

Comment: @Ostati Updated the answer. See also https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/pull/125

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
<field name="MessageObject" layout="${message}" layoutType="System.Object" />
```

then make logging with:

```
_logger.LogInformation("{@ExampleObject}", exampleLoggingObject);
```

The output is:

```
 "Message": {
     "ExecutionTime": 12,
     "Level": "Information",
     "Type": "ABC",
     ....
 }
```